# NestJS serialization from snake_case to camelCase

Tags: serialization, nestjs, class-transformer, mikro-orm

I want to achieve automatic serialization/deserialization of JSON request/response body for NestJS controllers, to be precise, automatically convert `snake_case` request body JSON keys to `camelCase` received at my controller handler and vice versa.

What I found is to use `class-transformer`'s `@Expose({ name: 'selling_price' })`, as on the example below (I'm using MikroORM):

```
// recipe.entity.ts
@Entity()
export class Recipe extends BaseEntity {
  @Property()
  name: string;
  
  @Expose({ name: 'selling_price' })
  @Property()
  sellingPrice: number;
}
```

```
// recipe.controller.ts
@Controller('recipes')
export class RecipeController {
  constructor(private readonly service: RecipeService) {}

  @Post()
  async createOne(@Body() data: Recipe): Promise<Recipe> {
    console.log(data);
    return this.service.createOne(data);
  }
}
```

```
// example request body
{
    "name": "Recipe 1",
    "selling_price": 50000
}
```

```
// log on the RecipeController.createOne handler method
{ name: 'Recipe 1',
  selling_price: 50000 }

// what I wanted on the log
{ name: 'Recipe 1',
  sellingPrice: 50000 }
```

There can be seen that the `@Expose` annotation works perfectly, but going further I want to be able to convert it as the attribute's name on the entity: `sellingPrice`, so I can directly pass the parsed request body to my service and to my repository method `this.recipeRepository.create(data)`. Current condition is the `sellingPrice` field would be null because there exists the `selling_price` field instead. If I don't use `@Expose`, the request JSON would need to be written on `camelCase` and that's not what I prefer.

I can do DTOs and constructors and assigning fields, but I think that's rather repetitive and I'll have a lot of fields to convert due to my naming preference: `snake_case` on JSON and database columns and `camelCase` on all of the JS/TS parts.

Is there a way I can do the trick cleanly? Maybe there's a solution already. Perhaps a global interceptor to convert all `snake_case` to `camel_case` but I'm not really sure how to implement one either.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the ORM's driver method `mapResult()` that is internally used for converting the raw results from database - all it does is basically to convert fieldNames (how the db column is called) to property names (how the entity property is called).

Comment: That'd be neat, I'm doing similar thing as well, but against the request body. Is there a correct way to get to the `mapResult()` driver method? Getting the driver instance and `EntityMetadata`? Or do you suggest me to borrow and write the `mapResult()` implementation for my own util function, perhaps? Anyway great ORM @MartinAdámek thanks for the library :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `mapResult()` method from the ORM, that is responsible for mapping raw db results (so snake_case for you) to entity property names (so camelCase for you):

```js
const meta = em.getMetadata().get('Recipe');
const data = {
  name: 'Recipe 1',
  selling_price: 50000,
};
const res = em.getDriver().mapResult(data, meta);
console.log(res); // dumps `{ name: 'Recipe 1', sellingPrice: 50000 }`
```

This method operates based on the entity metadata, changing keys from `fieldName` (which defaults to the value based on selected naming strategy).

Comment: Thank you! That works like a charm. I ended up using this on my controller and probably will setup a kind of decorator to make it looks cleaner